# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null even though it's been defined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

***In App.js***

```
<Router>
     <Confirmation path="/confirmation/:token" />
</Router>
```

***In Confirmation.js***

```
function Confirmation(props) {
  const verificationMessage = document.getElementById("verification-message");
  const token = props.token;
  // console.log(token);

  fetch(`/api/confirmation/${token}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // console.log(data.status);
      if (data.status === "alreadyVerified") {
        verificationMessage.innerHTML = "You have already been verified!";
      } else {
        console.log("already verified");
      }
    });

  return (
    <div className="confirmation">
      <h5>
        <span id="verification-message">You have been successfully verified!</span> Please navigate
        back to{" "}
        <Link to="/login" style={link_style}>
          <span className="confirmation__toLogin">login page</span>
        </Link>{" "}
        to sign on!
      </h5>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Even though verificationMessage has been defined, it has a value of null when trying to insert the message into HTML.

Error message:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should not manually mutate the DOM in React. Instead, you could move the fetch call to a `useEffect` and set the values you need with a `useState` (or do it the old-school way using class component), and then pass the data you need down to the JSX.

Answer (score 1):

```
Why need to set innerHTML .
   

    const {useState, useEffect} = React; 
       function Confirmation(props) {
          const [verificationMessage, setVerificationMessage] = useState(""); 
          const token = props.token;
          // console.log(token);
        
        useEffect(() => {

             fetch(`/api/confirmation/${token}`)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                  // console.log(data.status);
                  if (data.status === "alreadyVerified") {
                    setVerificationMessage("You have already been verified!");
                  } else {
                    console.log("already verified");
                  }
                });
    
    
    }, [])
          
        
          return (
            <div className="confirmation">
              <h5>
                <span id="verification-message">{verificationMessage}</span> Please navigate
                back to{" "}
                <Link to="/login" style={link_style}>
                  <span className="confirmation__toLogin">login page</span>
                </Link>{" "}
                to sign on!
              </h5>
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm currently very new to react and this helped a lot.